# JS Logical Insanity

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, google-sheets-api

This code returns `min`, how is this possible?

```
if(prices[i] == 1000 && min == 53){
  if(prices[i] < min){
    return min;
  }
  return prices[i];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values are strings. When you use `==` to compare them to numbers, the numbers are first (internally) converted to strings. However, the `<` compares the two strings *as strings*, and as such the string "1000" is in fact less than the string "53", because "1" comes before "5" in the character set.

Answer (score 3):

Funny things happen when you compare strings and not numbers

```js
console.log("strings", "1000" < "53")
console.log("numbers", 1000 < 53)
```